# Scala Spark reverse grouping of groupBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by

Im trying to reverse (flatten out) the grouping created on a RDD in Scala, like this: https://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-groupby-example/

Basically what i have is a key - value where the value is a list. I want to flatten that out. I cant figure out how to go about it, im thinking it must lie in flatmap somehow, but i cant figure out the syntax. Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data (input and current output), along with the code you used to get this grouping?

Answer (score -1):

You should provide some code in order to answer your question, but here is how you can flatten a `groupBy` by leveraging `flatMap` (I am using a code snippet similar to the "Spark groupBy Example Using Scala"). For now, I assume you are working with an RDD of strings.

```
val v = Array("foo", "bar", "foobarz")
val rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(v)
val kvRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] = rdd.groupBy(x => x) // your group by function goes here
// if you explicitly want to keep the key and generate an RDD of tuples
val pairRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = kvRDD.flatMap({ case (k: String, v: Iterable[String]) => v.map(i => (k, i))})
// or if you just want to undo the grouping without preserving the key
val origRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = kvRDD.flatMap({ case (_: String, v: Iterable[String]) => v})
```

Comment: The OP has an RDD with (key, value) pairs. This answer does not answer the question.

Comment: "what i have is a key - value where the value is a list. I want to flatten that out."

Exactly what happens at the 3rd line of code :)