# Sorting elements inside nested list in an RDD (Scala/Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sorting, rdd

I'm trying to sort the elements inside every nested list of an RDD object that looks like this:

org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, List[List[String]])]

Example of how unsorted could look like:

```
(342, List(List([banana], [apple]), List([orange], [lemon])))
(342, List(List([coconut], [carrot]), List([watermelon], [kiwi])))
(794, List(List([strawberry], [carrot]), List([lemon], [orange])))
```

And want the output to be like this (contents of nested lists sorted in alphabetical descending order):

```
(342, List(List([apple], [banana]), List([lemon], [orange])))
(342, List(List([carrot], [coconut]), List([kiwi], [watermelon])))
(794, List(List([orange], [strawberry]), List([carrot], [lemon])))
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Initial idea was to do "explode"/reverse the structure that resembles a groupByKey, so I would have 6 elements in my rdd and no nested lists (instead of 3 nested) looking somewhat like this (342, List([banana], [apple])). Then I could sort each of these lists in the tuples. Found another post that tried something similar, but couldn't make it work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742432/scala-spark-reverse-grouping-of-groupby)

Comment: Solved it @sinanspd, and added solution to question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Can you post answer

Comment: @Rajasekhar posted an answer now. Sorry didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it doing the following (reverse group structure and sort non-nested lists (note that RDD structure is changed tho - didn't matter in this case).

```
data.flatMap(x => x._2.map(i => (x._1, i))).mapValues(x => x.sorted)
```